# XSLT org.apache.fop.fo.extensions.svg.SVGElement.getDimension Could not set base URL for svg

Tags: xml, svg, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to implement SVG inside an instream-foreign-object below is the code snip it; this is a code section from a XSLT (1.0);

```
<xsl:template name="Draft">
    <fo:block-container>
        <fo:block>
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:base="http://example.org/today/" >
                    <svg:defs>
                        <svg:font-face font-family="sample">
                            <svg:font-face-src>
                                <svg:font-face-uri href="sample.ttf"/>
                            </svg:font-face-src>
                        </svg:font-face>
                    </svg:defs>
                    <svg:text>
                        DRAFT
                    </svg:text>
                </svg:svg>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

now when I am trying to convert from xml to pdf it is giving me below error:

```
org.apache.fop.fo.extensions.svg.SVGElement.getDimension Could not set base URL for svg
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
                at java.base/java.net.URL.fromURI(URL.java:721)
                at java.base/java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1139)
                at org.apache.fop.fo.extensions.svg.SVGElement.getDimension(SVGElement.java:77)
.
.
.
```

So can you please help me to understand why we are seeing this error?

Comment: Does `href="sample.ttf"` point to an existing file?

Comment: And the sample https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/fo/embedding.fo.pdf suggests you either want to set `width` and `height` on the `svg:svg` root element or on the outer `fo:instream-foreign-object`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes that is an embed-url font that we suppose to call internally with    fop -c <file_name which refers embed-url font def > option. But yes as of now we are not calling with fop -c  rather we are using curl command where that embed-url font reference is not being passed

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes before posting this I already gone through to that pdf link but I hadn't see they are using both xmlns:svg and xml:base tags; rather I would like to know more about this xml:base DTD functionality particularly inside fo:instream-foreign-object with svg, it would be good if you have any quick guide for that as well.

Comment: I have added the tag for XSL-FO, let's wait for the experts what they have to say which attributes are mandatory.

Comment: What happens if you omit the `xml:base` and refer to the font as `http://example.org/today/sample.ttf`?

Comment: @TonyGraham have to give a try so the code will be below? 
 <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <svg:defs>
                        <svg:font-face font-family="sample">
                            <svg:font-face-src>
                                <svg:font-face-uri href="http://example.org/today/sample.ttf?"/>
                            </svg:font-face-src>
                        </svg:font-face>
                    </svg:defs>
                    <svg:text>
                        DRAFT
                    </svg:text>
                </svg:svg>

Comment: I expect so, although you have an extra `?` at the end of the `href`. Without the `xml:base`, the base URL of the SVG will ordinarily be the base URL of the document.

Comment: @TonyGraham I will be trying that but what is the RCA for which I am getting the exception ? So that I can specifically look into that.

Comment: I don't use FOP, but it seems that FOP recognises only URLs that start with 'file:/' as absolute URLs. See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#MalformedURL. I don't know why it cares, but it does.

Comment: @TonyGraham So this will be my code? <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:base="file:///PATH/for/config/sample.xml" >
                    <svg:defs>
                        <svg:font-face font-family="sample">
                            <svg:font-face-src>
                                <svg:font-face-uri href="sample.ttf"/>
                            </svg:font-face-src>
                        </svg:font-face>
                    </svg:defs>
                    <svg:text>
                        DRAFT
                    </svg:text>
                </svg:svg>

Comment: @TonyGraham where file:///PATH/for/config/sample.xml have that font metrics definition for sample.ttf

Comment: @TonyGraham also i do find one link where they are saying it got deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xml:base#browser_compatibility

Comment: @TonyGraham can we have a alternative solution /tag rather using SVG which can be processed by fop-2.8 for same functionality ?  (As i found that same piece of code is working for fop-1.1 but not for 2.8)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know that much about FOP.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running FOP from the command line, your document has a base URI. Now that you've shown that you can have `sample.ttf` on your file system, I suggest putting the full path to `sample.ttf`

```
<svg:svg xmlns:svg="w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg:defs>
    <svg:font-face font-family="sample">
      <svg:font-face-src>
        <svg:font-face-uri href="file:///PATH/for/config/sample.ttf"/> 
      </svg:font-face-src>
    </svg:font-face>
  </svg:defs>
  <svg:text> DRAFT </svg:text>
</svg:svg>
```

From https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#svg-url, it appears that FOP could find the font from a HTTP URL.

Comment: may be we are missing that as of now we are using curl instead of fop (using fop is under plan only not implemented yet ); so will it be the same solution if we use curl

Comment: yes internally it will call fop only

Comment: <fo:instream-foreign-object>
        <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1100" height="1150">
            <svg:defs>
                <svg:font-face font-family="SampleReg">
                    <svg:font-face-src>
                        <svg:font-face-uri href="file:///{$Config_from_HTTPurl_Of_CURL}/fold/Sample.ttf"/>
                    </svg:font-face-src>
                </svg:font-face>
             </svg:defs>
             <svg:text font-family="SampleReg">
                 DRAFT
             </svg:text>
         </svg:svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>

Comment: Tried this still not working